# Skip specific string in a numeric column while using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29063/pgfplots-skip-the-first-row-of-a-table-on-which-there-are-nan-values-why), `NaN` string is omitted as mentioned in the manual of pgfplots package. My input data contains `UnDf` and I want to omit/skip this value.

Here is sample code from the question I have mentioned. If `UnDf`s are replaced with `NaN`, this sample code can be compiled. However, I need to omit `UnDf`s as `NaN`s are omitted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
0   UnDf 1   1
1   1   2   UnDf
2   1.2 UnDf 2
3   2   3   1
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\foreach \n in {1,...,3}{
\addplot table[
    header=false,
    x index = 0,
    y index = \n]{testdata.dat};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the PGF math engine only recognises `nan` as missing values. With the following code snippet, which is based on the code for interpreting `nan`s found in `pgfmathfloat.code.tex`, `UnDf`s are also treated as missing values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% Treat "UnDf" (regardless of letter case) as "nan"
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname pgffltA@U\endcsname{\pgfflt@readundef}
\expandafter\def\csname pgffltA@u\endcsname{\pgfflt@readundef}
\def\pgfflt@readundef #1#2#3{%
    \def\pgfflt@readnan@ok{1}%
    \if#1n\else\if#1N\else\def\pgfflt@readnan@ok{0}\fi\fi
    \if#2d\else\if#2D\else\def\pgfflt@readnan@ok{0}\fi\fi
    \if#3f\else\if#3F\else\def\pgfflt@readnan@ok{0}\fi\fi
    \if\pgfflt@readnan@ok1%
        \pgfmathfloat@a@S=3\relax%
        \pgfmathfloat@a@Mtok={0.0}%
        \pgfmathfloat@a@E=0%
        \expandafter\pgfflt@finish
    \else
        \def\pgfflt@readnan@{\pgfflt@error #1#2#3}%
        \expandafter\pgfflt@readnan@
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
0   UnDf 1   1
1   1   2   unDF
2   1.2 UnDf 2
3   2   3   1
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\foreach \n in {1,...,3}{
\addplot table[
    header=false,
    x index = 0,
    y index = \n]{testdata.dat};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Jake, you seem to be the guru on SX for `pgfplots`; I'm having some issues with setting it up, are you available for a chat? (didn't know how else to reach you, so I chose to comment on a random post of yours...)

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: Sure, I'll be available later today (in about two hours)