# Negative values in dat file are not plotted using PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

It is going to be trivial but I can't figure out what is wrong with the following.

I have `dat` file containing exactly this:

```
-6.13     -25.2630334555     
-0.14     -21.3855065611     
4.97       -16.396737203     
9.97       -12.3655278402    
14.96     -4.4686133113     
19.89     0     
24.96     4.5277219529      
29.93     1.7377940655      
34.8      0
```

When I am trying to plot these values like

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$\vartheta\ [^\circ\mathrm{C}]$},
ylabel={$\Delta C/C_{20}\ \mathrm{[\%]}$},
legend pos = south east,
legend entries = {vzorek 1},
grid = both,
xmin=-7,
xmax=40
]
\addplot[smooth,green,mark=+]   table {data_lab1/kapacity_vzorek1.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

the first line is omitted - value for `-6.13` is not plotted. But why?

Comment: add `table[headers=false]`

Comment: But where. I tried ´\addplot[smooth,green,mark=+]   table[headers=false] {data_lab1/kapacity_vzorek1.dat};´ and put ´table[headers=false]´ in axis environment. Both didn't work.

Comment: The first one should work. I might be misremembering maybe also try `header=false`. Sorry I don't have access to TeX now.

Comment: Now it works. Excellent memory :)

Comment: That shouldn't actually happen, and does in fact not happen on my system, up to date TeX Live 2017. (Which version of `pgfplots` do you have?) As mentioned in the manual and in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29063 the first row in a table is considered a header only if it contains non-numerical entries.