# The option header=false does not work to consider first row containing symbolic name in data text file with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, options

I want to do something simple. I have the following data in a text file called example.txt:

a 1.254 
b 0.995 
c 2.782
d 5.722

I want to plot all the data with a, b, c and on X axis but pgfplots think first line is a header so I want to use header=false to consider the first row (what I put in comment) but I get the error "tikz does not know header".

Here my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ 
ylabel={Y}, 
xlabel={X}, 
symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d}, 
xtick={a,b,c,d},
xticklabels={AAAA,BBBB, CCCC,DDDD} 
] 
\addplot +[only marks,color=red] table {example.txt}; 
%\addplot +[header=false,only marks,color=red] table {example.txt}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: `\addplot +[only marks,color=red] table[header=false,] {example.txt};`, i.e. pass `header=false` to the table, not to the plot.

Comment: I knew it was something simple.... thank you for the fast answer!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Done. I'll be happy to remove it if other users feel it should not be there.

Comment: Good find! Do you want to close your question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29063/pgfplots-skip-the-first-row-of-a-table-on-which-there-are-nan-values-why ? I believe that your question is still very useful since, as long as one does not know the root of the problem, it is hard to know which key words one should look for, and once you know, you do no longer ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be happy to remove this if you feel like you want to delete your question, and I am writing this because @CarLaTeX asked me to.

### Answer to the question

You need to put `header=false` to the options of the table, not the plot.

### Side remark

You make things slightly easier for others if you use `filecontents` to add the data. That way you may attract more users to play with the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{example.txt}
a 1.254 
b 0.995 
c 2.782
d 5.722
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ 
ylabel={Y}, 
xlabel={X}, 
symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d}, 
xtick={a,b,c,d},
xticklabels={AAAA,BBBB, CCCC,DDDD} 
] 
\addplot +[only marks,color=red] table[header=false] {example.txt}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even my question was (a bit) stupid ^^, I am using quite a lot pgfplots but this time I was not used to this case were options are set for the table, so I think it may help other people. If you think it was just a too silly question, I have no problem if you want to "clean" the content of tex.stackechange ;-)

Comment: @Willi I apologize if I made the impression that your question is stupid, it is certainly not. I am more worried that it is likely a duplicate, but the earlier posts are hard to find.

Comment: no actually it was written there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29063/pgfplots-skip-the-first-row-of-a-table-on-which-there-are-nan-values-why but I must have been tired and I did not notice the position of options (concerning the table and not addplot)